# Keep a datetime local field from changing

Tags: html, angularjs, flask

I like the way the datetime-local field looks in html, but when I add it to my database I believe it is converting the time to GMT.  How do I keep GMT from changing so I can show the time in a normal format?  When I Switch the field to datetime it doesn't have the same look, it doesn't have it formatted so you can select from a calender, click up/down, etc.

html:

```
<input type="datetime-local" ng-model="mealtime" placeholder="mealtime"></br>
```

angularJs:

```
$scope.addMeal = function() {
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      url: "/api/addMeal/",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: JSON.stringify({us: $scope.user, token:$scope.token, mealtime:$scope.mealtime, calories:$scope.calories, memo:$scope.memo}),
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.meals = response['data']
        console
      });

};
```

app.py

```
        mealtime = request.json["mealtime"]
        mealday = mealtime[:-14]
        mealhours = mealtime[-13:-5]
        mymeal = Meal(time = mealhours, day = mealday).save()
```

Also, I've found that if I add {{datetime}} to my code, the angular is immediately converting my datetime to 0z time, ie "2015-01-01T13:01:00.000Z"

Comment: Can you provide a sample data and the database which you are using?

Comment: I think I need to convert it to its local time before I chop it into day and hours, I'm just not sure the best way to do this